# How to get rid of this error message from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, console.log

I want to get rid of the following warning message apparently Firebase is sending to my console.

I've search for "firebase" in my console and got "690 results in 49 files."

I'm confused about why this is showing up and what I can do about it.

What, exactly, is triggering it? Is it possible to get rid of the warning message or not? If so, how, exactly?

> It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
>   When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
>   the individual SDK components you intend to use.
>
> For the module builds, these are available in the following manner
>   (replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):
>
> CommonJS Modules:
> `const firebase = require('firebase/app');`
> `require('firebase/<PACKAGE>');`
>
> ES Modules:
> `import firebase from 'firebase/app';`
> `import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';`
>
> Typescript:
> `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';`
> `import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's telling you to import only the packages you need vs importing the kitchen sink / dev package. See [Add Firebase to your JavaScript Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) and notice the various packages.

> ```
> firebase-app — The core firebase client (required)
> firebase-auth — Firebase Authentication (optional)
> firebase-database — Firebase Realtime Database (optional)
> firebase-firestore — Cloud Firestore (optional)
> firebase-storage — Cloud Storage (optional)
> firebase-messaging — Firebase Cloud Messaging (optional)
> firebase-functions — Cloud Functions for Firebase (optional)
> ```

Comment: Right. But what is it that's importing the kitchen sink? I need to delete that line then replace it with the others. There must something like `import firebase from 'firebase'` and I'm trying to find that so that I can delete it. But I have no idea where that import is or what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

#### only import what you need

```
import Firebase from 'firebase/app' //firebase-app
import 'firebase/firestore' //
import { firebase } from 'firebase/storage' //firebase-storage
```